# Windows Phone 8.1 Background task: crashes when debugging

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to develop I background task, that simply updates a badge on a tile in Windows Phone.

I think I implemented everything correctly, but when I fire of the back ground task in debug mode, the app simply crashes.

Here is my code:

**The Background class**

```
 public sealed class TileBadgeUpdate : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        updateBadge();
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private void updateBadge()
    {
        var badgeXML = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeNumber);
        var badge = badgeXML.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as XmlElement;
        badge.SetAttribute("value", "20");
        var badgeNotification = new BadgeNotification(badgeXML);
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badgeNotification);
    }
```

I register the background task in the "OnNavigatedTo" of one of my pages. I can successfully debug this code:

```
        foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            task.Value.Unregister(true);
        }

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.Name = "NewBGTask";
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "POCTimesheetEntry.TileBadgeUpdate";
        builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
        var ret = builder.Register();
```

In the AppxManifest

I have registered the background task:

[image: Declaration]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Matthew

Comment: Can you navigate to a break point on `Run` method? Did you create 2 different projects? Did you switch process in Debug Location toolbar?

Comment: Hello, I have a breakpoint in the run of my class. It does not reach the breakpoint. I have added a class Library of type 'Windows Runtime Component (Windows Phone)' 

Picture: http://i.imgur.com/hyPH0Ew.png

Comment: I found the solution myself: I had to add a reference to the background task project in the app project. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi, BadgeUpdateManager reference not there in the Windows RunTime component Lib. Right? So how you managed to update the tile from bg task ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have created BackgroundTask (Windows Run Time Component) project separately. **IT IS MUST WHEN YOU CREATE BACKGROUND TASK IN WINDOWS PHONE 8.1 APP, YOU CREATE SEPARATE PROJECT AS WINDOWS COMPONENT**
2. See if you have forgot to **add reference** of Backgroud Task **Project** to **your Project**.

In my case I forgot to add reference of background task project hence geofencetask.Completed was not getting called.

Comment: Hi, BadgeUpdateManager reference not there in the Windows RunTime component Lib. Right? So how we ca manage to update the tile from bg task ?