# How WHATSAPP push notification works in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, notifications, windows-phone-8.1

I am a Windows lover and a windows phone developer.

I am developing apps targeting windows phone. Since My latest app needs push notification, I implemented it using WNS [Windows Push Notification Service]. It works well in all devices.

But I am facing a drawback on this because we don't have any extra api service for getting the notification list. So a user can see his notification only by tapping on it in the notification bar. If a user swipe it over means , user can't access it any more.

- Noticed same in Whatsapp windows application,
- Whatsapp is not running foreground/background, Number of
  notifications are shown in the action center.
- Internet connection makes turned off, And tap on any notification.
- WhatApp application opens, and we can see that all messages are
  updated in the queue of each user/group.

How this is handled? What technique used in it ? Can we store toast list in background ? Please find the related link [How to handle WNS push notifications in Windows Phone 8.1 -silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562659/how-to-handle-wns-push-notifications-in-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a wide search I found a solution for handling to store notification data when application is not running by adding `Background Service (Windows Runtime Component) Lib`. Then we can user `Raw notification` for providing data from the server. Raw notification will work on background task.

reference [Windows Phone 8.1 Background task: crashes when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765888/windows-phone-8-1-background-task-crashes-when-debugging)